# Cant include boost thread - possible boost library configuration issue

Tags: boost, cygwin, codeblocks

I am currently attempting to use boost threading in a simple project.
My ide is Codeblocks 13.12 and I am using GCC Cygwin as my compiler.
This is what my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

I have also added `"c:\cygwin64\lib"` in my linker search directories. 
This directory contains the file `libboost_thread.dll.a` so I have added `libboost_thread` in link libraries under the liker settings tab.
Now when I attempt to build this code I get the errors

```
||=== Build: Debug in TestCodeBlocks (compiler: Cygwin GCC) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':|
\usr\include\boost\system\error_code.hpp|222|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
 relocation truncated to fit||R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::generic_category()'|
\usr\include\boost\system\error_code.hpp|223|undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'|
 relocation truncated to fit||R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::generic_category()'|
\usr\include\boost\system\error_code.hpp|224|undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'|
 relocation truncated to fit||R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

just add -lboost_system to the compilation line

```
g++ hello.cc -lboost_system
```

Comment: yep that did the trick dont know why I had to add boost_system ?

Comment: Because forementioned functions will be called during static initialization before main, even if you only included this header file.